# Error 404 on creating a calendar with Google Calendar Api

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I just wrote this code that is supposed to check if calendar exists and if not create one. Well it returns error 404 when I try to create a calendar and the calendar does NOT appear. Any ideas? I blanked out clientid, secret, app key.

```
            import gflags
            import httplib2
            import sys, traceback

            from apiclient.discovery import build
            from oauth2client.file import Storage
            from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
            from oauth2client.tools import run

            FLAGS = gflags.FLAGS

            # Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate. This
            # sample uses OAuth 2.0, and we set up the OAuth2WebServerFlow with
            # the information it needs to authenticate. Note that it is called
            # the Web Server Flow, but it can also handle the flow for native
            # applications
            # The client_id and client_secret are copied from the API Access tab on
            # the Google APIs Console
            FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
                    client_id='MY_CLIENT_ID',
                    client_secret='MY_SECRET',
                    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                    user_agent='KUDOS_CALENDAR/v1')

            # To disable the local server feature, uncomment the following line:
            # FLAGS.auth_local_webserver = False

            # If the Credentials don't exist or are invalid, run through the native client
            # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
            # Credentials will get written back to a file.
            storage = Storage('calendar.dat')
            credentials = storage.get()
            if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
                credentials = run(FLOW, storage)

            # Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it
            # with our good Credentials.
            http = httplib2.Http()
            http = credentials.authorize(http)

            # Build a service object for interacting with the API. Visit
            # the Google APIs Console
            # to get a developerKey for your own application.
            service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http,
                         developerKey='MY_DEV_KEY')
            kudos_calendar = None
            try:
                kudos_calendar = service.calendarList().get(calendarId='KudosCalendar').execute()
            except:
                print 'Calendar KudosCalendar does not exist!'
                print 'Creating one right now...'
                kudos_calendar_entry = {
                    'id': 'KudosCalendar'
                }

                kudos_calendar = service.calendarList().insert(body=kudos_calendar_entry).execute()
```

Comment: This is tough to diagnose without more detail, like seeing the actual information in your account, but I'd suggest you take a look at your calendar list.  What I guess happened is that the first time you ran in you created the `KudosCalendar`, and after that each time you tested your code, you were trying to create a new calendar on top of the old one you already created.  You probably would have to delete the old calendar with that ID to create a new one.

Comment: Hi jdotjdot, I thought that as well, but I am looking at my calendar list and KudosCalendar is not present...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a way around. I am not sure what exactly are google abstractions reflecting, but I am pretty sure one cannot just create calendar list. However if you just create a calendar then everything goes fine and then one can use calendar id to access calendarlist entry corresponding to that calendar.

Ufff.. Horribly confusing. Also while trying to do that I found at least two bugs in example python codes given in docs. I think they still did not properly rolled out v3.